# Unable to replace part of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to use string.replace() function but it is not working

here is what is i did;

```
const replaceTemplate = function (temp, product) {
  let output = temp.replace(/{%PRODUCTNAME%}/g, product.productName);
  console.log(product.productName);
  output = temp.replace(/{%IMAGE%}/g, product.image);
  output = temp.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
  output = temp.replace(/{%FROM%}/g, product.from);
  output = temp.replace(/{%NUTRIENTS%}/g, product.nutrients);
  output = temp.replace(/{%QUANTITY%}/g, product.quantity);
  output = temp.replace(/{%ID%}/g, product.id);
  output = temp.replace(/{%DESCRIPTION%}/g, product.description);

  if (!product.organic)
    output = output.replace(/{%NOT-ORGANIC%}/g, "not_organic");

  return output;
};
```

This function is supposed to replace all placeholders in template argument being passed.

```
const cardsHTML = dataObj
      .map((el) => replaceTemplate(tempCard, el))
      .join("");
```

This is my function call. dataObj is javascript object and tempcard is a html code template. I am reading it using

```
const tempCard = fs.readFileSync(`./templates/template-card.html`, "utf-8");
```

Placeholders in tempCard are not getting replaced at all.

Comment: You call `.replace()` and store its return value in `output` -> `output = temp.replace(...)`. Eight times. Therefor the function will always only replace the last placeholder.

Comment: `.replace()` returns a string so chain those calls: `output = temp.replace(...).replace(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your replacements is starting from the original `temp`, not the result of the previous replacements. So you only get the last one. Except for the first one, they need to replace from `output`, not `temp`.

```
const replaceTemplate = function (temp, product) {
  let output = temp.replace(/{%PRODUCTNAME%}/g, product.productName);
  console.log(product.productName);
  output = output.replace(/{%IMAGE%}/g, product.image);
  output = output.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
  output = output.replace(/{%FROM%}/g, product.from);
  output = output.replace(/{%NUTRIENTS%}/g, product.nutrients);
  output = output.replace(/{%QUANTITY%}/g, product.quantity);
  output = output.replace(/{%ID%}/g, product.id);
  output = output.replace(/{%DESCRIPTION%}/g, product.description);

  if (!product.organic)
    output = output.replace(/{%NOT-ORGANIC%}/g, "not_organic");

  return output;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to save each value you are replacing in a single variable, that's the problem

```
 const replaceTemplate = function (temp, product) {
  let output = temp;
  output = output.replace(/{%PRODUCTNAME%}/g, product.productName);
  output = output.replace(/{%IMAGE%}/g, product.image);
  output = output.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
  output = output.replace(/{%FROM%}/g, product.from);
  output = output.replace(/{%NUTRIENTS%}/g, product.nutrients);
  output = output.replace(/{%QUANTITY%}/g, product.quantity);
  output = output.replace(/{%ID%}/g, product.id);
  output = output.replace(/{%DESCRIPTION%}/g, product.description);

  if (!product.organic)
    output = output.replace(/{%NOT-ORGANIC%}/g, "not_organic");

  return output;
};
```